# UIActivityViewController open and close events

Tags: objective-c, uiactivityviewcontroller

I'm trying to hook into the `UIActivityViewController` as I need to stop some code from running whilst the view is open.

When the view is closed, I need to start my class again.

```
UIActivityViewController *activityController = [[UIActivityViewController alloc] initWithActivityItems:activityItems applicationActivities:nil];
[activityController setTitle:code];
[activityController setExcludedActivityTypes:self.excludedItems];
[activityController setCompletionHandler:^(NSString *activityType, BOOL completed) {
    self.label.text = @"Scanning...";
    [self.qrScannerView start];
}];
```

And when it's opened, I need to stop it:

```
[self presentViewController:activityController animated:YES completion:^{
    [self.qrScannerView stop];
}];
```

This seems to work once, but afterwards it'll continue to do run. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Maybe something to do with the reference to `self` in the block? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21113963/is-the-weakself-strongself-dance-really-necessary-when-referencing-self-inside-a

Comment: Ah. I figured it out. My `start` and `stop` events would only fire if `_canScan` was the right bool value. It seems they were being set back quicker than the completions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by my custom class changing the values of `stopped` and `started` too soon, so  I could never close.