# Objective-C __strong equivalent in Swift

Tags: swift

In Objective-C we cast values as __weak to avoid retain cycles in certain situations.

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21114626/1951992) explains why __strong is useful

```
__weak typeof (self) weakSelf = self;

self.block = ^{
    [weakSelf methodA];        
};
```

Do we specifically need a __strong self equivalent in Swift and is it available ? If so, what is the syntax please ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Correctly handle Weak Self in Swift Blocks with Arguments](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24468336/how-to-correctly-handle-weak-self-in-swift-blocks-with-arguments)

Comment: `__strong` is the default for variables and ivars in both Obj-C and Swift. I think the only reason Obj-C has that keyword is consistency. You don't need to write it explicitly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is nothing like `__strong` in Swift because all variables are strong by default.

Below is the Swift equivalent of the above code:

```
self.block = { [weak self] in
  self?.methodA()
}
```

If you want to keep `self` alive during the execution of the block, you can do something like below:

```
self.block = { [weak self] in
  guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
  strongSelf.methodA()
}
```

In the above code, `strongSelf` will create a strong reference to `weakSelf` inside the block so that the weak reference won't get deallocated while strong one is alive *(which in our case until the block finishes executing)*.

Please note that none of the options above will cause *retain cycles*.

Comment: Is it fair to say that the strongSelf reference that holds on to the weakSelf reference, causes a transient retain cycle ? Once the block finishes executing the retain cycle is broken. What you think ?

Comment: Yes, it is safe to say that the block holds a strong reference so there is a transient cycle there which keeps self alive. But the main point is that it shouldn't lead to a some sort of deadlock which causes self to never get deallocated. Using weak keyword ensures that to never happen by creating a strong reference to a weak pointer.

Comment: Thanks for getting back to me.